# how to store particluar video in json format?

Tags: javascript, json

```
[{
  name:"plylistname",
  videos:["","",""],
  userid:"userid"
}]
```

In the above JSON structure  how we can add videos dynamically  from the selected videos using javascript

Comment: You haven't provided enough information in your question.  What are the selected videos, how do they related to the JSON fragment and much more.  Please consider adding a lot more information to the question.

Comment: If you need to store the binary data of a video to be stored in JSON, you can utilize base32 or base64 encoding. But... _but_... why would you want to do that?

Comment: I mean i need to create the new Playlist using the existing videos using only java script and html

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to add something into the videos array? If so, just use push.

```
var myJson = [{
  name:"plylistname",
  videos:["","",""],
  userid:"userid"
}];

myJson[0].videos.push('Video 1');
myJson[0].videos.push('Video 2');
```

Comment: thanks bro do know how to create new dynamic playlist using the html and javscript